# Using SQLAlchemyAuthenticatorPlugin login with email or username

Tags: authentication, sqlalchemy

Right now i'm working on a site which uses the SQLAlchemyAuthenticatorPlugin. You need username and password to login.
I would like to add a login with email and password. So in the end it should be possible to use email/password or username/password to login.
Right now it looks like this:

```
sqlauth = SQLAlchemyAuthenticatorPlugin(model.User, model.meta.Session)
sqlauth.translations['user_name'] = 'email'
sql_user_md = SQLAlchemyUserMDPlugin(model.User, model.meta.Session)
sql_user_md.translations['user_name'] = 'email'
```

With sqlauth.translations i'm now able to successfully login with email/password. But of course username/password isn't working anymore.
Any ideas on how to make both options work at the same time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SQLAlchemy plugins are fairly simple](http://svn.repoze.org/whoplugins/whoalchemy/trunk/repoze/who/plugins/sa.py); you can either monkey-patch them or implement your own version of the plugins, like

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm.exc import NoResultFound, MultipleResultsFound
import repoze.who.plugins.sa
class _EmailBaseSQLAlchemyPlugin(object)
    default_translations = {'user_name': "user_name", 'email': 'email',
                            'validate_password': 'validate_password'}

    def get_user(self, login):
        login_type = 'email' if '@' in login else 'user_name'
        login_attr = getattr(self.user_class, self.translations[login_type])
        query = self.dbsession.query(self.user_class)
        query = query.filter(login_attr == login)

        try:
            return query.one()
        except (NoResultFound, MultipleResultsFound):
            # As recommended in the docs for repoze.who, it's important to
            # verify that there's only _one_ matching userid.
            return None

class EmailSQLAlchemyAuthenticatorPlugin(_EmailBaseSQLAlchemyPlugin,
          repoze.who.plugins.sa.SQLAlchemyAuthenticatorPlugin):
    pass
class EmailSQLAlchemyUserMDPlugin(_EmailBaseSQLAlchemyPlugin,
          repoze.who.plugins.sa.SQLAlchemyUserMDPlugin):
    pass

sqlauth = EmailSQLAlchemyAuthenticatorPlugin(model.User, model.meta.Session)
sql_user_md = SQLAlchemyUserMDPlugin(model.User, model.meta.Session)
```